# Find and Change Class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose we have table like that :

```
<table id="tbl">
  <tr><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>def</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>abc</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>def</td></tr>
</table>
```

How can I change the row's class to below class when a row contains abc?

```
.hightlight
{
 background-color:yellow;
 color:blue;
}
```

I have used this jquery command, but not working :

```
$('#tbl tr td:contains("abc")').attr('class','hightlight');
```

Comment: I've tried your code on jsfiddle and it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/T6HrP/ , where is the javascript instruction called ?

Comment: [Seems to work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/RbrCz/)

Comment: For me works fine! [http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/tuKSd/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/tuKSd/1/)

Comment: In any cases use [$(document).ready(function () {...}](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 2):

Code in fiddle works fine @ http://jsfiddle.net/Jayendra/nLYuW/

If you want whole row, you need to use parent

```
$('#tbl tr td:contains("abc")').parent().attr('class','hightlight');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working as-is. You could try changing your `.attr()` to `addClass()` as an alternate method.

```
$('#tbl tr td:contains("abc")').addClass('hightlight');
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/WEFad/).

If you would like to add the CSS class to the entire row, then use the `.parent()` selector.

```
$('#tbl tr td:contains("abc")').parent().addClass('hightlight');
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also use this:

```
$("#tbl tr").filter(':has(td:contains("abc"))').addClass("highlight");
```